# Node.JS Memory Limit Exceeded Error in Fetching Data from APIs in for Loop

Tags: node.js

I am getting memory limit exceeded in nodejs.

Basically, I am hitting a same API in for loop which fetches data for different users then updates it in the mongoDB.
Any idea How to resolved this without increasing the memory size in nodejs?

Can this be solved with Generator Class? Just need a heads up on this problem.

Needs heads up How should we solve this?

Comment: Search and try something first, then provide more info. Five links to similar questions are provided above.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I have tried using steam and generator classes was not able to achieve it.
Just wanted to know if anyone has done something like this and in which direction should I look for the solution?
Moreover the links which you have mentioned are to increase the memory usage which is not the desired solution as vertical scaling has its own limitations.